# Facebook Ads targeting: Reaching multiple age groups with same ad

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When doing ad targeting using the Marketing API how do I target 2 different groups at the same time?
I want to target users between 18 and 25 who are in college and users over 30 that has recently got engaged or married.
Can it be done using targeting flexible specs or do I need two create two separate ads?

The facebook documentation only shows how to target one age group at the same time.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.9

However you can target multiple generations, but for me those are too broad.

Comment: did you come up with anything on this?